# Convert relative time in words into formatted date format in python

Tags: python, datetime, time, python-datetime

How to convert relative time that are expressed in humanised words like "-100 days, -6 months, -1 year, +1 year" into YYYY-MM-DD format?

Comment: I am expecting a string output with a YYYY-MM-DD format. By they I already found a module to this one.

Comment: @VanPeer please check my answer, I put that in detail. thank you for interest to my question. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I am posting my answer to help others if they need the same thing.

What I am doing is developing a CLI application, part of the process is user will input starting date and end date, but I want the user to use a relative time like the following:

*(for the sake of a an example date, October 23, 2017 would be the current date)*

```
$ cliapp.py --start_time="10 days ago" --end_time="yesterday" 
10 days ago is "2017-10-13"
yesterday is "2017-10-22"


$ cliapp.py --start_time="tomorrow" 
tomorrow is "2017-10-24"
```

to accomplish this I found dateparser module and works exactly what I need.

here is the link to it: https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

If you have other solution, feel free to put on comment. :)